# How do you share your Facebook 'Look Back' video on YouTube?

Tags: facebook, youtube, sharing, facebook-lookback

Is there a way to share my Facebook Look Back video to my YouTube account?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to this URL.

   https://m.facebook.com/lookback?_rdr

   It is the mobile version of your facebook lookback page. I used Google Chrome to open the link.
2. Start playing the video.
3. Right click on the video and choose `Save Video As...`.
4. Select a location on your PC and click save.
5. Once done, go to

   https://www.youtube.com/upload
6. Once there, select your file previously downloaded on step 4 for uploading.
7. Upload your video.
8. Wait for it to process.
9. Enjoy!